# Password field in register page on WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I instaled WooCommerce, but on register page, on the form I have only one field (e-mail), but I need and password field on the page.

How to create a field with the password on this page?

Answer (score 1):

@Asking: Go to Woocommerce -> Settings -> Accounts & Privacy -> Account creation

Uncheck -> When creating an account, automatically generate an account password

This will enable the password field on Register Page.